# problem with specifying colClasses in read.csv in R

Tags: r, csv

I am trying to specify colClasses in read.csv in an attempt to speed up the reading of csv file. However, I encounter the following problem:

assuming that i have a file called "t.csv":

```
"a","b"
"x","0"
```

Then, if I run the following in R:

```
data <- read.csv('t.csv' , stringsAsFactors=FALSE, check.names=FALSE , comment.char='', colClasses= c('character','numeric') )
```

I got this error:

```
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  scan() expected 'a real', got '"0"'
```

At first I thought it was the problem with my quote. But using quote='"' in read.csv didn't help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your second column is not `numeric` as it is quoted -- that makes it text.

So read it as text, then call `as.numeric(...)` on the column.  Or alter the file.

Answer (score 3):

Further to Dirk,

You can simply drop the colClasses argument and the file will read in fine.

```
data <- read.csv('t.csv' , stringsAsFactors=FALSE, check.names=FALSE , comment.char='')
str(data)
```

Gives:

```
> str(data)
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ a: chr "x"
 $ b: int 0
> class(data$b)
[1] "integer"
```

You should be able to do everything you want with that second column now.

GL

Comment: Or equivalently use `colClasses=c('character',NA)` which cause `read.csv` to use `type.convert` function on second column.